# use .replace(string,string) instead of .replace(char,char)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to replace pieces of string which I retrieve from an xml-file. but the .replace(string,string) won't be selected. It automatically goes to .replace(char,char).

How do I prevent or solve this?

In this code the first replace works for strings. the second tries to replace chars.

```
    string strSubject = elemConf.Element("MailSubject").value;

    strMailTitleSubject = strSubject.Replace("[[Number]]", db.Database.Where(b 
=> b.Id == id).Select(b => b.File).Single());

    string strBody= xelemConf.Element("MailBody").value;

    strMailBody = strBody.Replace("[[box]]", db.DimensionerShipments.Where(b => 
b.Id == id).Select(b => b.box).ToString().Single());
```

Comment: please format your question

Comment: What types are File and box properties in your lambda?

Comment: `.ToString().Single()` is your problem. String is (among other things) an enumeration of characters. `ToString().Single()` returns one character if the string has one character; otherwise, it throws an exception. None of that is anything you want. Get rid of `ToString()` there. Maybe you want `.Single().ToString()`, if `b.box` isn't a string. Or `.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString()`, I can't say.

Comment: If you only want one item from `DimensionerShipments`, use `db.DimensionerShipments.Single(b => b.Id == id).box`...

Comment: @EdPlunkett .Single().ToString() solved it. Thank you!